# Why are the supremums of this linearly interpolated function equal?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

**Original question:**

> Suppose $f$ is a real, continuous function defined on the closed set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^1$. Prove that there exists real, continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$ such that $g(x) = f(x) \forall x \in E$.

**Proof:**

> Suppose $f$ is a real, continuous function defined on the closed set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^1$. Then, $E^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Then $E^c$ can be expressed as a union of an at most countable collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals and we can write $$E^c = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} (a_i, b_i) \cup (-\infty, a_0) \cup (b_0, +\infty).$$ where either $n$ is finite or $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i < b_i$. Next, define $g$ as
>
> $g(x) =
>                 \begin{cases}
>                 f(x) & \text{if $x \in E$} \\
>                 f(a_i)+(x-a_i)\frac{f(b_i)-f(a_i)}{b_i-a_i} & \text{if $x \in (a_i, b_i)$} \\
>                 f(b_0) & \text{if $x \in (b_0, +\infty)$} \\
>                 f(a_0) & \text{if $x \in (-\infty, a_0)$}
>                 \end{cases}$
>
> Clearly, $g$ is an extension of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$ and it remains to show that $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Now, to show that $g$ is continuous if $x\in E$, I found a proof that begins with:

> Given $x\in E$ and $\epsilon>0$, by the continuity of $f$ on $E, \exists \delta_0>0$ such that $$y\in E \textrm{ and } |y-x|<\delta_0 \implies |f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2.$$ If there exists a $z\in E$ with $x-\delta_0<z<x$, set $\delta_1=x-z$ and note that
> \begin{equation*}
>         \sup_{x-\delta_1<y<x} |g(y)-g(x)| = \sup \{|f(y)-f(x)|:y\in E, x-\delta_1<y<x\} \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon
>     \end{equation*}

**My question**: Why is it true that $\sup_{x-\delta_1<y<x} |g(y)-g(x)| = \sup \{|f(y)-f(x)|:y\in E, x-\delta_1<y<x\}$? I think that this is true because $g$ is a linear extension of $f$. Why can the $\sup$ be restricted to the $y$-values $x-\delta_1<y<x$?

Comment: What are $a_0, b_0, a_i, b_i$ ?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I edited my question to add that information.

Comment: $E=\{0,1,2\}$ defeats your condition $b_i<a_{i+1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Ah, quite interesting, thanks for pointing that out! I don't need that ordering at all I now think. All the $(a_i, b_i)$, are just finite pairwise disjoint intervals.

Comment: $g$ agrees with $f$ on $E$ - that shows $\ge$ in the equality of suprema you are asking about. For $\le$, suppose $y \in [a_i, b_i]$ and note that $|g(y) - g(x) | = |g(y) - f(x)| \le \max \{| f(a_i) - f(x)|, |f(b_i) - f(x)|\}$. This appeals to $g$ extending $f$ linearly, as you suggested.

Comment: Note that the intervals $(-\infty, a_0)$ and $ (b_0, +\infty)$ are only *optional components* which occur when $E$ is bounded from below or above. But that does not affect the proof.

Comment: @PaulFrost Can you please explain how that relates to the equality in the two suprema?

Comment: You do not need that. If $E$ is not bounded from below, then you may **formally** set $a_0 = -\infty$ and $(-\infty,-\infty) = \emptyset$. Similarly $b_0 = + \infty$ if $E$ is not bounded from above.

Comment: @t.y Can you please elaborate, preferably in words, why $|g(y)-g(x)|=|g(y)-f(x)| \le \max \{|f(a_i)-f(x)|, |f(b_i)-f(x)|\}$, for the choice of $y$ in your comment?

Comment: @t.y So far, I understand that if $y=a_i$, then $|g(y)-f(x)| = |f(a_i)-f(x)|$ and similarly, if $y=b_i$, then $|g(y)-f(x)| = |f(b_i)-f(x)|$. But, if $a_i<y<b_i$, then how does the relationship hold?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Draw (or visualize) the possibility $f(a_i) < f(b_i) < f(x)$, and draw $g$ on $[a_i, b_i]$. Then you can see for any $y \in [a_i, b_i]$, $f(a_i)$ is further away from $f(x)$ than $g(y)$, i.e. $|g(y) - g(x)| \le |f(a_i) - f(x)|$. The same thing happens in the other three possibilities - perhaps with $b_i$ in place of $a_i$ - which I've sketched here: https://i.imgur.com/j116bHs.png Note that $z, x \in E$ means $z \le a_i < b_i \le x$.

Comment: Actually, what I drew is misleading / incomplete; there is also the possibility that $f(x)$ is between $f(a_i)$ and $f(b_i)$. But the same ideas apply towards the same conclusion.